# Validate WCF Service

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, wcf, service

I'd like to write a license management based on a wcf services.

**How can I ensure that the (end)-user/"hacker" can not replace our license management services with a corrupt server?**

Our license server is hosted on our server in the internet. When the server send corrupt data to the client the complete license management concept is destroyed.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to solve something which cannot be solved. Once you provide application to the client and client deploys it on his computer he can of course do whatever he wants with your application. Even if you hardcode some security check into the application client can reverse engineer and modify your code. You can reduce his chances by using some obfuscation of your libraries but still anything deployed on client machine can be cheated. That is the reason why warez exists and there is no bullet proof solution.

If you don't want client to cheat you, build your application as web based and host it on your servers. Client will pay for access / account and he will not be able to avoid your licensing strategy.

If you want some high quality licensing strategy which is harder to cheat try to buy some existing solution instead of creating your own.

Answer (score 0):

I think [public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) might be an answer here. I'm not an expert in security so I might be really wrong, but as far as I can see it you may have public key for decryption hardcoded into your service consumer and private key for encryption on your license server. Then the workflow might be as follows:

1. Client generates some random message and sends to the server
2. Server encrypts this message and returns back encrypted result
3. Client tries to decrypt received message and if it matches original one then server is validated successfully.

Of course this may be done only assuming that you can guarantee that your service consumer app cannot be hacked, but otherwise I do not see any point hacking service anyway.

Comment: The only problem is: I can even overwrite hardcoded variables by reflection(If I know the structure). So I can inject a different public key. Have you an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: IMO, if you can hack client then nothing will help you. If you can change the app (and change public key compiled into it) then what will stop from just removing server validation code?

Comment: Of course, he can create a new app based on our source code. But that takes a very long time and a lot of skill. Reflecting the value is done in a few minutes. But maybe you are right. Even Bilzards "Star Craft 2" was "hacked"